# How to get accelerators with pyhook

Tags: python, input, pyhook

I have been tasked with capturing the user's keystrokes, including combinations of keys, such as ctrl-O and shift-F11.

I can get keydown events, but I do not see a means to get combinations of events.

Must I tracks keys such as ctrl, shift, alt, and see if they were down at the time another key down event was received or is there an easier way?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: 2.7 and pyhook 1.5.1